# Pop up with userdata using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im making a website for an assignment on school.

You can post a question on this site and then just wait for someone to contact you.
I want the contact data to open in a pop up. I have tried this with php and javascript but the pop up is on every post the same. It seems that the browser makes one pop up and then uses that everywhere. This is my code:

```
     <?php
      include("php/opendb.php");

      $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM requests INNER JOIN user_data ON user_data.user_id = requests.user_id WHERE type = 1 ORDER BY date DESC');
      $stmt->execute();
      $settings = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($settings as $row){
    $title = $row["title"];
    $user = $row["user_id"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $phone = $row["phone_number"];
    echo "<section id='post'><h3>" .$title. "</h3> <br>
    <p class='posttext'>" .$row["addinfo"]. "<br>
    <p class='posttext'> user_id: " .$user. "<br>
    <p class='posttext'> email: " .$email. "<br>
    <p class='posttext'> name: " .$name. "<br>
    <p class='posttext'> phone number: " .$phone. "<br>
    <div class ='message'>
    <a href='#plusbalk'><img id='heart' onclick='parent.document.getElementById(\"heart\").src=\"/images/heart2.png\"' src='../images/heart.png' /></a>
    <a href='#plusbalk'><img id='message' onclick=\"profilepopup()\" src='../images/messenger.png' /></a></p></div></section> ";

    echo "<div id='profilepopup' class='modal'>
      <!-- pop up content -->
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <span onclick='document.getElementById('profilepopup').style.display = 'none' 'class='close' >&times;</span>

        <div class='modal-header'>

          <h2> Contact informatie </h2>

        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
        <p class='posttext'> user_id: " .$user. "<br>
        <p class='posttext'> email: " .$email. "<br>
        <p class='posttext'> name: " .$name. "<br>
        <p class='posttext'> phone number: " .$phone. "<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> ";

  }

?>
```

I have used simple javascript for the pop up.

The first echo shows the contact information in the message directly on the site, this works!
But the second echo is for the pop up and then it doesn't work and every pop up is the same with the exact same contact information every time.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: `every pop up is the same with the exact same contact information every time`... yes `<div id='profilepopup'` can be repeated multiple times. But IDs must be unique in HTML. Otherwise the javascript doesn't know which one to open, so it chooses the first one it finds every time. Make your PHP generate a unique ID for each popup you render.

Comment: how does that work in php? how can I add an unique ID and to where?

Comment: just use a counter. e.g. `$i = 0;` before your foreach loop, ... then in the foreach `onclick=\"profilepopup(".$i".)\"`... `echo "<div id='profilepopup".$i."'`... `document.getElementById('profilepopup".$i."').style.display = 'none'`... at the end of the loop `$i++;`. And of course, amend your profilepopup function so that it accepts the argument and uses it to pop up the right div. I can't see that function, so I can't tell you what to change. But hopefully it's obvious now I've shown you the idea.

Comment: Yes thank you man! the different pop ups now show on the backend of the site. Only my javascript doesnt work anymore.

function profilepopup() {
  var profilepopup = document.getElementById("profilepopup");
  profilepopup.style.display = "block";
}

how can I fix this with a variable

Comment: I would have hoped it would be obvious...have you genuinely no idea how to accept a variable into a Javascript function and then use it? That is pretty basic stuff in Javascript (or any language, for that matter)...it's not clear where you're stuck. Did you try anything? Give it a go, you might learn a little. If it doesn't work, show me your attempt and I'll help you some more.